# Dependency Injection in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I completely fell in love with Dependency Injection. I enjoy the way it gives you the possibility to follow SOLID principles, the way it prevents Spaghetti Code. I used Dagger in one of my Android project and everything is more clean, modular and testable.
Now I'm working on a Swift project. I would like to follow this kind of design pattern without using any third-party libraries (due to lacks of the current codebase and project commitments). So, I decided to create an homemade implementation.

```
import UIKit

class DependencyContainer {
    private var dependencies = [String: AnyObject]()

    struct Static {
        static var instance: DependencyContainer?
    }

    static var shared: DependencyContainer {
        if Static.instance == nil {
            Static.instance = DependencyContainer()
        }

        return Static.instance!
    }

    init() {
        AppDelegate.print("Dependency container instantiated")
    }

    func resolve(_ classIdentifier: String) -> AnyObject {
        if dependencies[classIdentifier] == nil {
            dependencies[classIdentifier] = getClassInstance(classIdentifier)
        }

        return dependencies[classIdentifier]!
    }

    private func getClassInstance(_ classIdentifier: String) -> AnyObject {
        var instance: AnyObject! = nil
        let classInstance = NSClassFromString(classIdentifier) as! NSObject.Type
        instance = classInstance.init()

        return instance
    }

    func dispose() {
        DependencyContainer.Static.instance = nil
    }
}
```

Where I need to inject a dependency I do it as follows:

```
dataRepository = DependencyContainer.shared.resolve(NSStringFromClass(DataRepositoryImplementation)) as! DataRepository
```

Everything is working fine at the moment but I think that there are lots of limitations with this kind of approach. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What do you have in your code is more a `Service Locator` than `Dependency Injection`.If you want to know the pros vs cons this [article](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#UsingAServiceLocator) of Martin Fowler is a must read !!

Comment: [Dependency injection means giving an object its instance variables. Really. That's it](http://www.jamesshore.com/Blog/Dependency-Injection-Demystified.html). DI does not require container nor singletons.

Comment: Here's another good article on DI to read: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/different-flavors-of-dependency-injection-in-swift

Comment: I really want to thank you guys for your answers. I just read what you suggested. What I want to achieve is to find a way to properly inject a dependency (constructor, property or parameter). At this point do you think the only way I have is to use Typhoon or Swinject?

Comment: @JJack_ You also might want to check weaver (https://github.com/scribd/Weaver). It allows you to declare dependencies in you classes via annotation. Based on that It auto generates the dependency injection containers for you and performs some pre compilation checks to ensure you dependency graph is correct.

Comment: To come back to your code, and if you don’t want to use a DI library, I would avoid the use of singletons and inject the container in your classes at init instead. I’d also avoid using on huge container but make one per class or module of the app. This will allow you to have more granularity in order to test more easily, but also override dependencies when you need to. I’d also create one protocol per container, exposing direct accessors to your injected objects. It’ll also make your classes easier to test since you’ll be able to use a fake container in your tests. I hope this help! Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

I know an ultra-light dependency injection container. [DIContainer](https://github.com/Tavernari/DIContainer)

It's nice because you can resolve the dependencies using `@Injected` before the properties, or if you prefer, you can call the method `resolve`.

For example:

```
@Injected(.githubService)
var githubService: FetchService

@Injected(.by(type: FetchService.self, withKey: "gitlab"))
var gitlabService: FetchService

@InjectedSafe
var externalService: ExternalSingletonService?
```

or

```
let githubService = try? Container.standard.resolve(.githubService)
let gitlabService = try? Container.standard.resolve(.by(type: FetchService.self, withKey: "gitlab"))
let externalService = try? Container.standard.resolve(.by(type: ExternalSingletonService.self))
```

I hope it helps you with your achievement.